# Why did the translator of Kafka's book "metamorphosis" choose past simple in the beginning of "the metamorphosis"?

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

As Gregor Samsa awoke one morning from uneasy dreams he found himself transformed in his bed into a gigantic insect. He was lying on his hard, as it were armor-plated, back and when he lifted his head a little he could see his dome-like brown belly divided into stiff arched segments on top of which the bed quilt could hardly keep in position and was about to slide off completely. His numerous legs, which were pitifully thin compared to the rest of his bulk, **waved** helplessly before his eyes.

Franz Kafka "the metamorphosis"

Why not "waving", he is now an insect so a change has been made so I think past continuous could fit here or is it to make the reader understand that now he is insect and as an  insect, from now on, he  always waves its legs or last reason for progressive use   is that it has already been used for lie"he is lying" so there is no use to repeat it (I don't think this one is a good reason to explain the use of past continuous)

Comment: **were waving** would stress the idea of the limb-action's *ongoingness* whereas the simple past conveys the simpler idea of the *nature* of that action: his legs were ineffective.  **wave** already contains the idea of a continuous movement, as it is not an action with a clear sense of goal or completion. So there's no call for the continuous.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the nature of that action'?

Answer (score 2):

The past continuous "were waving" could have been used. But there is no need for past continuous. In a past tense narrative the event "the legs waved" is a past event and simple past is correct.

German (the source language) [doesn't have past continuous](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18488/how-do-you-communicate-in-german-a-continuous-action-in-the-past). In this case the translator had a choice, and chose the shorter more direct structure. I'm no expert in Kafka, but that seems in keeping with the direct and matter-of-fact way he describes the Kafkaesque situations he creates.

Comment: I  think I know the reason . Past continuous for" lay "is used as a background  for the scene : all the following actions will result from this situation. What do you think of it ?

Comment: That is perfectly reasonable.